# Otimização em SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tem alguma maneira de melhorar esse trecho?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não ficou muito claro se por otimização você se refere a escrita ou eficiência, mas caso seja escrita, acredito que o ideal seria substituir isso por um IN, exemplo:

```
SELECT products.name, categories.name FROM products
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = products.id_categories
WHERE products.amount > 100 AND categories.id IN (1, 2, 3, 6, 9);
```

Comment: Se for otimização do desempenho, basta criar um índice na coluna `categories`.

Answer (score 1):

Olá viva com base nas respostas anteriores efetuas a query com recurso ao IN e crias indexação caso não exista, a solução completa de forma a otimizar a tua consulta.

**Consulta**

```
SELECT products.name, categories.name FROM products
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = products.id_categories
WHERE products.amount > 100 AND categories.id IN (1, 2, 3, 6, 9);
```

**Indexação**

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_products_id_categories
ON products (id_categories);
```